# Internet browser crash

Tags: firefox, chromium, 15.04, crash

I installed Ubuntu 15.0.4 64 bit. My mainboard is an ASUS M2N-PLUS SLI vista edition with AMD CPU, with 4GB of RAM and an nVidia 8500 GT video card.

When I start Firefox, after opening a new tab Firefox crashes and restarts.

Sometimes, when I open it for first time, it will also crash. I tried to install Midori and Chromium, but all of these browsers crash as well, although chromium appears to crash less.

I set up flash player and `pepperflashplugin`, but browsers are still crashing and I can not use the Internet as a result.

When I run `firefox` from command line I see

```
firefox &
[1] 4070
mostafa@mfaridi-ubuntu:~$ 
(process:4070): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
(process:4099): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
WARNING: content window passed to PrivateBrowsingUtils.isWindowPrivate. Use isContentWindowPrivate instead (but only for frame scripts).
pbu_isWindowPrivate@resource://gre/modules/PrivateBrowsingUtils.jsm:25:14
pbs<@resource://unity/observer.js:38:71
Observer.prototype.observe@resource://unity/observer.js:77:24
get_contentWindow@chrome://global/content/bindings/browser.xml:404:54
get_securityUI@chrome://global/content/bindings/browser.xml:654:17
browser_XBL_Constructor@chrome://global/content/bindings/browser.xml:778:17
WARNING: content window passed to PrivateBrowsingUtils.isWindowPrivate. Use isContentWindowPrivate instead (but only for frame scripts).
pbu_isWindowPrivate@resource://gre/modules/PrivateBrowsingUtils.jsm:25:14
pbs<@resource://unity/observer.js:38:71
Observer.prototype.observe@resource://unity/observer.js:77:24
WARNING: content window passed to PrivateBrowsingUtils.isWindowPrivate. Use isContentWindowPrivate instead (but only for frame scripts).
pbu_isWindowPrivate@resource://gre/modules/PrivateBrowsingUtils.jsm:25:14
pbs<@resource://unity/observer.js:38:71
Observer.prototype.observe@resource://unity/observer.js:77:24
WARNING: content window passed to PrivateBrowsingUtils.isWindowPrivate. Use isContentWindowPrivate instead (but only for frame scripts).
pbu_isWindowPrivate@resource://gre/modules/PrivateBrowsingUtils.jsm:25:14
pbs<@resource://unity/observer.js:38:71
Observer.prototype.observe@resource://unity/observer.js:77:24
1431173849082   addons.xpi  WARN    Exception running bootstrap method shutdown on webapps-team@lists.launchpad.net: ReferenceError: sss is not defined (resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> file:///usr/share/mozilla/extensions/%7Bec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384%7D/webapps-team@lists.launchpad.net/bootstrap.js:72:4) JS Stack trace: shutdown@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> file:///usr/share/mozilla/extensions/%7Bec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384%7D/webapps-team@bootstrap.js:72:5 < XPI_callBootstrapMethod@XPIProvider.jsm:4442:9 < shutdownObserver@XPIProvider.jsm:2185:13
```

Comment: Do you get an error if you run `firefox` from the terminal?

Comment: when I run firefox from termnal I see these

Comment: See what? I'm looking for the terminal output when you run firefox, and it crashes.

Comment: For me it crashes when I try to open address bar too early.

Comment: How I can get full log about crash internet browser ?can this is happen because of hardware drivers?

Comment: You could check out crash details by putting this, in the URL:  about:crashes

Answer (score 1):

The fact that all the browsers you tried experience crashes seems to suggest that your environment has some problem rather than a specific browser. Seeing that your PC is equipped with nvidia hardware, perhaps a video driver issue?

Did you install the proprietary nvidia driver? The default "nouveau" driver is getting better, but from my experience is still far from being as stable as the one provided by nvidia. To check/install the proprietary driver type "Additional drivers" in the dash (Windows key).

The next thing I would try would be to disable all the installed Firefox add-ons, as the errors you are getting seems to be coming from Ubuntu's Unity integration add-on to Firefox. From within Firefox, type "about:addons", and then go to the "Extensions" tab. From there, disable anything that has "Ubuntu" or "Unity" in it. If it still crashes, try disabling every extensions. At last, you could try clearing your Firefox profile by issuing the following command (while Firefox is closed):

```
mv ~/.mozilla ~/.mozilla_bak
```

Good luck!